# Welch t-test, adjust p-value on permutation based FDR in R

Tags: r, t-test, fdr, q-value

I would need some help to find a way to compute q-values from Welch p-values in R, using  permutation FDR method, as for SAM technique.

Assuming my data are as follow

```
x = matrix(rnorm(1000*3),nrow=1000)
y = matrix(rnorm(1000*3),nrow=1000)
```

I can obtain a list of Welch p-values for each 'row x-vs-y' as follow

```
pvalues = sapply(1:1000, function(n) t.test(x[n,], y[n,])$p.val)
```

How can I then adjust the p-values using permutation fdr?
As far as I can see,  `p.adjust` cannot do this, `samr` allows only t-statistic or  wilcoxon and, I cannot find any package that can help me out.
Any suggestions?